# Mongoid - using distinct in scope

Tags: mongoid, distinct

I have the following model:

```
class Message
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :tags,        :type => Array

  scope :contained_tags, distinct(:tags)
end
```

Because `distinct` syntax is not a method of the Model, but a `Criteria`. So exception `undefined method 'distinct' for Message:Class (NoMethodError)` is raised for the model above.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: `all.distinct(:tags)` ??

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
def self.contained_tags
  scoped.distinct(:tags)
end
```

1. It acts **exactly** as a scope
2. You can even chain scopes; for example:

   Message.only_active.contained_tags

NOTE: in case you are using an older version of mongoid and '**scoped**' does not work for you, then use: `criteria.distinct(:tags)`